# INSERT a column into a table with SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the best approach to insert a calculated column grouped by an ID into another column where the ID matches?

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cs.customerNumber, cs.totalOrderCost as paymentDue, 
       SUM(p.amount) as paymentMade 
FROM customerSales cs LEFT OUTER JOIN payments p 
          ON cs.customerNumber = p.customerNumber 
GROUP BY cs.customerNumber;
```

which returns customerNumber, paymentDue, paymentMade, calculated correctly.

In the table customerSales, there are two columns: customerNumber and totalOrderCost. I want to add the "paymentMade" column (summed from the payments column and grouped by customerNumber) into the customerSales table.

This approach:

```
ALTER TABLE customerSales 
    ADD COLUMN paymentMade DECIMAL; 
INSERT INTO customerSales(paymentMade) 
SELECT SUM(p.amount) as paymentMade 
FROM payments p 
GROUP BY p.customerNumber;
```

gives the error "Field customerNumber doesn't have a default value".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should use **update** not insert and do update ... where customerNumber= ...

Comment: Why do you write an `INSERT`  query with only one column while there might be other columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have added the column to the table schema:

```
 ALTER TABLE customerSales ADD COLUMN paymentMade DECIMAL;
```

you should use update based on the subquery:

```
    UPDATE customerSales  
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT cs.customerNumber
        , cs.totalOrderCost as paymentDue
        , SUM(p.amount) as paymentMade 
        FROM customerSales cs 
        INNER JOIN payments p ON cs.customerNumber = p.customerNumber 
        GROUP BY cs.customerNumber
    ) t  ON customerSales.customerNumber =t.customerNumber
    SET paymentMade = t.paymentMade
```